# Overheat from voltage dividing circuit?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, overheat

I want to create a circuit that is capable of delivering 1V, 3A from a 5V, 3A power supply.
To do this im using a voltage dividing circuit with a 1k ohm resistor (r1) and 220ohm resistor (r2). The resistors im using are rated 1/4W. Will they overheat?
Thanks

Comment: A voltage divider is *not* the correct circuit here. Use a voltage regulator.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this algebraically? You can draw a schematic, solve for node voltages and currents, and find power for each element (which can be compared to its rating or used to calculate temperature given its thermal resistance to ambient air)

Comment: I really dont know how to do that, I would call my self a beginner in electronics

Comment: This is like trying to regulate the speed of your car to 30km/h by fixing it so that the brake is always pressed a certain amount. It's wasteful in energy and only gets you to a speed to 30km/h at ONE position of the gas pedal. If you push the gas pedal more, you go slower than if the brake wasn't there but still go faster than 30km/h. If you push the gas pedal less, you end up going slower than 30km/h. All it does is reduce everything across the board in a wasteful way by a certain amount. It doesn't regulate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't overheat, but it won't work either.

Let's analyze this voltage divider design from 5V using R1=\$1000\Omega\$ and R2=\$220\Omega\$.

Open-circuit voltage (no-load condition) at midpoint of divider:

\$ Vo = {5V}\times\frac{R2}{(R1 + R2)}= {5V}\times\frac{220\Omega}{(1000\Omega + 220\Omega)} = 0.901V \$

Bias current through the series connection of R1 + R2:

\$ iBias = \frac{5V}{(R1 + R2)} = \frac{5V}{(1000\Omega + 220\Omega)} = 0.004098A \$

Power dissipation in each resistor depends on Ohm's law and the definition of power:

\$ V = i\times{R} \$

\$ P = V\times{i} \$

\$ P = i^2\times{R} \$

\$ P_{R1} = {iBias}^2\times{R1}= {0.004098A}^2\times{1000\Omega} = 16.79 mW\$

\$ P_{R2} = {iBias}^2\times{R2}= {0.004098A}^2\times{220\Omega} = 3.69 mW \$

Now what happens when you connect a load that demands 3A from a 1V source? That is like putting a \$0.333333\Omega\$ resistor in parallel with the R2 \$220\Omega\$ resistor, which changes the design of the voltage divider...

Voltage at midpoint of divider under 3A load:

\$ R_{L} = \frac{1V}{3A} = 0.333333\Omega \$

\$ R2_{L} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R_{L}}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{220\Omega}+\frac{1}{0.333333\Omega}} = 0.3328\Omega \$

(Notice that since \$R_{L}\$ is so much smaller than R2, it almost doesn't matter what the value of R2 is.)

\$ Vo_{L} = {5V}\times\frac{R2_{L}}{(R1 + R2_{L})}= {5V}\times\frac{0.3328\Omega}{(1000\Omega + 0.3328\Omega)} = 0.001663V \$

Bias current through the series connection of \$R1 + R2_{L}\$:

\$ iBias_{L} = \frac{5V}{(1000\Omega + 0.3328\Omega)} = 0.004998A \$

\$ P_{R1} = {iBias_{L}}^2\times{R1}= {0.004998A}^2\times{1000\Omega} = 24.9833 mW\$

\$ P_{R2_{L}} = {iBias_{L}}^2\times{R2_{L}}= {0.004998A}^2\times{0.3328\Omega} = 0.008 mW \$

So even though power dissipation seems not to be a problem in this case, the output voltage is not well regulated. The output voltage is sensitive to the amount of load current drawn. With no load, the output voltage is close to the design target of 1V, but with a load that draws 3A from 1A, the output voltage drops to near zero.

The **Thevenin equivalent** of this resistor divider is an ideal voltage source with some source resistance in series, which models how much the voltage drops depending on the load current. 3A is a lot of load current, so this needs to be considered.

\$ V_{Thevenin} = {5V}\times\frac{R2}{(R1 + R2)}= {5V}\times\frac{220\Omega}{(1000\Omega + 220\Omega)} = 0.901V \$

\$ R_{Thevenin} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1000\Omega}+\frac{1}{220\Omega}} = 180\Omega \$

The short-circuit output current of this model is then

\$ i_{shortCircuitThevenin} = \frac{V_{Thevenin}}{R_{Thevenin}} = \frac{0.901V}{180\Omega} = 0.005A = 5mA \$

This is far less than the design target of 3000mA.

Notice that this short-circuit current is also close to the bias current. This is a design flaw with using a resistor divider this way: **there's no way to get a large output current from a resistor divider, without burning an impractical amount of power in the resistor divider.** In reality, resistor dividers are normally used only to set up reference voltages with fairly low bias currents. The bias current needs to be quite a lot larger than the load current, otherwise the accuracy is impacted.

By the way, the maximum amount of power transfer happens when the load resistance equals the source resistance. Higher resistance draws less current, lower resistance draws more current but at less voltage. Open circuit draws zero power because V x 0A = 0W, and ideal short-circuit draws zero power because 0V x i = 0W. (A real short-circuit does draw some power because wires have some resistance, so we never get exactly to short circuit condition. There could be little or no power delivered to the load, but still very damaging amount of power burned in some internal structure of the source.)

\$ P_{Maximum} = \frac{(\frac{V_{Thevenin}}{2})^2}{R_{Thevenin}} = \frac{(\frac{0.901V}{2})^2}{180\Omega} = 1.127 mW \$

This resistor divider approach can only provide about 1mW or less to the load, and your design target is 3000mW at the 1V@3A operating point.

You could make this circuit work better as a voltage regulator, if you add an NPN BJT transistor configured as an **emitter follower** (there is lots of info on web). This is a circuit building block that uses a small signal (the output of the voltage divider) to control a larger signal (the 3A load current). Of course there's no free lunch, you now have to worry about power dissipation of the emitter follower transistor. And the emitter voltage is not identical to the base voltage, so the resistor divider has to compensate for the Vbe voltage drop. However this technique is much less sensitive to variations in load current.

If you've never used transistors before, there are a couple of intermediate steps you will need to go through before you can drive a 3A output current. First get some 2N3904 and 2N2222 transistors; these are old but widely available small-signal transistors. The 2N2222 is good up to about 0.5A, so start with small-scale load testing of 0.01A, 0.02A, 0.05A, 0.1A, 0.2A, 0.5A. Most likely you will need a heatsink on the power transistor.

There are other techniques that could be used to make a regulated 1V@3A voltage regulator, like replacing the bottom part of the resistor divider with a **Zener diode** for improved accuracy, but you still need a large power transistor to handle the high current output.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing amount of detail, I will definitely look into transistors.